# Ho do I make this code segment faster in matlab?

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization

```
function [D] = distChiSq( W, X )
%%% find the  Chi2Dist distance between each weight vector and X
% W is nxd
m = size(W,1);  n = size(X,1);
k = size(W,2);
mOnes = ones(1,m); D = zeros(m,n);
for i=1:n
    Xi = X(i,:);  XiRep = Xi( mOnes, : );
    s = XiRep + W;                        /************/
    d = XiRep - W;                        /************/
    D(:,i) = sum( d.^2 ./ (s+eps), 2 );   /************/
end
D = D/2;
```

This is an part from my Chi2 distance calculation between Weight matrix and Data. Marked lines are the most consuming lines of the all code. Is there any way to do it faster in MATLAB?

If data is nxm than `s = nxm, d = nxm` and D is keeping the distances. n is number of instances and m is number of variables.

Comment: have you run your code through the MATLAB profiler?

Comment: yeap, I already point the lines based on profiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, this is so much fun with [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun):

```
s = bsxfun( @plus, permute( X, [1 3 2] ), permute( W, [3 1 2] ) ) + eps;
d = bsxfun( @minus, permute( X, [1 3 2] ), permute( W, [3 1 2] ) ).^2;
D = .5*sum( d./s, 3 );
```

Comment: You are all about the `bsxfun`, aren't you :)

Comment: It is good for sure, but still closely slow execution. I will choose GPU development.

Comment: @Shai, what kind of speedup did you get when using this vs the code that was provided originally? I'm not convinced that using `bsxfun` over `+` or `-` provides any sort of speed benefit.

Comment: @DangKhoa I eliminated the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to the great answer from Shai:

```
F = @(a,b) (a-b).^2 ./ (a+b+eps);
D = sum(bsxfun(F, permute(X, [3 1 2]), permute(W, [1 3 2])), 3)/2;
```